# C++ Placing values in Structs inside a vector and then re-sizing to fit more

Tags: c++, vector, struct, resize

```
typedef unsigned int uint;

class hash_table {
    struct key_line {
        bool empty();
        string word;
        vector<int> lineholder;
        bool operator==(const string &key) { return key == word; };
        bool operator!=(const string &key) { return key != word; };
    };
public:
    hash_table();
    void insert(const string &, const int &);
    const vector<int> find1(const string&);
private:
    uint hash(const string &);
    int nextprime(int);
    int qprobe(const string &);
    void resize();

    int inusenow;
    int num_inuse;
    int max_inuse;
    vector<key_line> table;
};
uint hash_table::hash(const string &key) {
    uint index = 0;
    const char *c = key.c_str();

    while (*c)
        index = ((index << 5) | (index >> 27)) + *c++;
    return index % table.size();
}

hash_table::hash_table() {
    int N = 41;
    table.assign(N, key_line());
    inusenow = 0;
    num_inuse = 0;
    max_inuse = N / 2;
}
void hash_table::insert(const string &key, const int &linenumber) {
    int index = qprobe(key);
    if (table[index].empty()) {
        table[index].word = key;
        table[index].lineholder.push_back(linenumber);
        if (++num_inuse >= max_inuse) {
            resize();
        }
        return;
    }
    if (table[index].word == key) {
        for (uint i = 0; i < table[index].lineholder.size(); i++) {
            if (table[index].lineholder[i] == linenumber) {
                return;
            }
        }
        table[index].lineholder.push_back(linenumber);
        return;
    }
}


int hash_table::qprobe(const string &key) {
    int index = hash(key);
    int k = 0;
    while (!table[index].empty() && table[index].word != key) {
        index += 2 * (++k) - 1;
        index = index % table.size();
    }
    return index;
}
void hash_table::resize() {
    vector<key_line> tmp_table(table);
    //for (int i = 0; i<(int)table.size(); i++) {
        //cout << "Word : " << table[i].word << "\n";
    //}
    //for (int i = 0; i<(int)table.size(); i++) {
    //  if (table[i].empty())
        //  tmp_table.push_back(table[i]);
//  }
    int N = nextprime(2 * table.size());
    inusenow = N;
    table.assign(N, key_line());
    num_inuse = 0;
    max_inuse = N / 2;
    table = tmp_table;

    cout << "resize";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    hash_table H;
    vector<string> cache; vector<string> token;
    vector<int> linenum;
    string holder, key, tmp, buf;
    string::iterator iv;
    stringstream ss;
    int count = 0;
    int linenumber = 0;
    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "Must have an additonal argument giving the name of the file you wish to search\n";
        return 0;
    }
    ifstream file;
    file.open(argv[1]);
    while (getline(file, holder)) {
        cache.push_back(holder);
        count = 0;
        for (iv = holder.begin(); iv != holder.end(); ++iv) {
            if (!isalnum(holder[count])) {
                holder[count] = ' ';
            }
            count++;
        }
        token.clear();
        ss.clear();
        stringstream ss(holder);
        while (ss >> buf) {
            H.insert(buf, linenumber);
            //token.push_back(buf);
        }
        //for (uint i = 0; i<token.size(); i++) {
        //  H.insert(token[i], linenumber);
        //}
        linenumber += 1;
    }
```

The purpose of this program is for it to be able to take in any sort of txt file and then hash it into a table.

The resize function is not increasing the size of the table and is overwriting table with the next table.

For example

if the table originally has an word at index 1 when it resizes the original is over written.

The functions empty, nextprime work.

Comment: Can you reduce this code to a [MCVE] leaving out all of the irrelevant parts please.

Comment: You never `resize` the table nor push into it. How should it change its size?

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ all unnecessary parts have been removed and yes i know its alot.

Comment: Daniel Jour table.assign(N,key_line()) creates an vector with size N

Comment: Daniel that the problem im having.